# Knockout function if values are equal

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

i've tried to scroll to an Element within an `ul` which is made with knockout. The Div should be scrolled to the Element, if a condition is true.

The code I have is:

```
    <div id="container">
                    <table>
                        <tbody data-bind="foreach: sequence">
                        <tr>
                            <td>M<span data-bind="text: $index"></span></td>
                            <td>
                                <ul data-bind="foreach: $data" class="verticalList">
                                    <li data-bind="css: {activeElement: $index()==simulator.activeIndex() && $parentContext.$index() ==simulator.machineIndex()}">
                                        <span >⊢</span>
                                        <span data-bind="text: $data.string, css: {some Condition}"></span>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
```

What I want to have:

There should be the ability to call a function on the `li` if $parentContext.$index() ==simulator.machineIndex() which gives me the `li`-Element, so that I can scroll to it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: if you can set up a sample `fiddle` on this it can will be easy . cheers

Comment: I don't really now how to make my own example code to a fiddle. I'm still new to this stuff. sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a [custom binding handler](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) is what you're looking for:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.elementScroller = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
        // First get the latest data that we're bound to
        var value = valueAccessor();

        // Next, whether or not the supplied model property is observable, get its current value
        var active = ko.unwrap(value);
        if (active) {
            // Now scroll some diff to this element
            $('#someScrollingDiv').animate({top: $(element).position().top});
        }
    }
};
```

And in your HTML:

```
<li data-bind="elementScroller: $index()==simulator.activeIndex() && $parentContext.$index() ==simulator.machineIndex(), css: {activeElement: $index()==simulator.activeIndex() && $parentContext.$index() ==simulator.machineIndex()}">
```

Comment: That is what I'm looking for!
At first I noticed I have to write that binding to the `tr`-tag to take the hole row.

But now I still have a problem: the div doesn't scroll to the given position, just to its end.
I've also tried: `$("#Container").scrollTop($(element).position().top));`

Comment: This does answer your original question I believe. Problem with scrolling the div to the given element is a question on it's own and requires a bit more context. Try and reproduce the problem using http://jsfiddle.net/